# Glassfish and JSF: Singleton not set for WebappClassLoader

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, intellij-idea, glassfish

I've done something that caused this error:

```
[#|2013-08-15T00:29:32.020+0600|WARNING|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.container.web.com.sun.enterprise.web|_ThreadID=91;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|StandardWrapperValve[Faces Servlet]: PWC1406: Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Singleton not set for WebappClassLoader (delegate=true; repositories=WEB-INF/classes/)
    at org.glassfish.weld.ACLSingletonProvider$ACLSingleton.get(ACLSingletonProvider.java:110)
    at org.jboss.weld.Container.instance(Container.java:54)
    at org.jboss.weld.jsf.WeldPhaseListener.instance(WeldPhaseListener.java:161)
    at org.jboss.weld.jsf.WeldPhaseListener.activateConversations(WeldPhaseListener.java:98)
    at org.jboss.weld.jsf.WeldPhaseListener.beforePhase(WeldPhaseListener.java:85)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.handleBeforePhase(Phase.java:228)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:99)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.doPhase(RestoreViewPhase.java:116)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1542)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:849)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:746)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1045)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:228)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

'Something' may be creating new Faces config file or adding new framework in IntelliJ IDEA IU-129.549 (I don't remember what exactly did I do). Without a success in a troubleshooting, I dropped Glassfish (v. 3.1.2) directory and recreated it, created new project including some frameworks (JSF, CDI, EJB, RESTful, application server and database classes). Created simple login and welcome pages (using Facelets, not JSP) and ran the application.

At first, auto-generated artifact "...:ejb exploded" hasn't been deployed (*Invalid ejb jar: it contains zero ejb*), at second, this error hasn't been gone, even after the recreating Glassfish directory and project! When I open **ht‮‭tp://localhost:8080/*%projectname%*/faces/**, I see a 500 error page with given above full trace. What's wrong? Also there were some problems with IDEA's JSF plugin, but now the IDE doesn't show me any errors.

Answer (score 0):

JSF plugin works fine in IDEA for me. Make sure you have the JSF facet enabled on your project settings. Would also make sure that under idea the source directories are marked as such (usually src/main/java, src/main/webapp, src/main/resources, each separately).

Hard to tell on the rest without taking a look at your pom.xml and project structure.

Comment: JSF facet is enabled, /src is marked as source directory. I created one more project with the same structure and frameworks - all work. Reloaded the server once more - all work with topic's project too. All I've done is adding beans.xml to WEB-INF directory, I don't think this was a reason not to work.

It would be good if anyone could tell what was the reason of this error.